# Paytm integration using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, payment-gateway, paytm

I am in a need to integrate Paytm in my website. I use .Net for server side and AngularJS for client side. Is there anyway to integrate Paytm on my website with AngularJS. Tried googling but couldn't find any solution.

Hope some of you should have already tried an approach how to integrate. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: i have same problem but i user nodejs for server side

Comment: The main issue is when you POST the paytmParams to paytm website - they response with POST http method on your callback URL and in angularjs or any SPA app/ UI Client you cannot read POST body json.